# Yii2: window.open from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2, window.open

I have a GridView of a index view with some columns. I added a print button that link to a URL that has to be opened in a new window.

[image: Print button in index.html]

This code work but the URL is not open in a new window.

```
'columns' => [
    'column1',
    'column2',
    'column3',
    'column4',
    'column5',
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{download} {update} {delete}',
        'buttons' => [
            'download' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a(
                    '<span class="fa fa-print"></span>',
                    '/disposicion-licencia/print-estival?id=' . $model->id,
                    [
                        'title' => 'Download',
                        'data-pjax' => '0',
                    ]
                );
            },
        ],
    ],
]
```

I think I need JavaScript code like this:

```
window.open('/disposicion-licencia/print-estival?id=$id');
```

But I don't know where to use it.

Comment: In your options for the link, add `'target' => '_blank'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new window you need 'target' => '_blank':

```
       return Html::a(
                '<span class="fa fa-print" ></span>',
                '/disposicion-licencia/print-estival?id=' . $model->id,
                [
                    'title' => 'Download',
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                    'target' => '_blank',
                ]
            );
```

Comment: You added it to the `<span>`... ;)